# Customize Generic Inquiry and Dashboard page

Tags: acumatica

I want to customize the Inquiry page and dashboard so that they would reload automatically in certain time, say 5 minutes interval. I was thinking if I could add custom javascript where I could set timeout for the period. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if this is for a basic dashboard purpose I would look at a browser extension to automatically refresh a page.

For example: https://www.guidingtech.com/12491/auto-refresh-pages-chrome-firefox-opera/